# Adding an empty value to the enum class

Tags: c#, wpf

Below is the `enum` class available in my code but, I want to add an empty value to it. After adding empty value to this class I am getting an error.

```
public enum AgentLevel : int 
{

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Location = 1,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute(Value="Head Quarter")]
        HeadQuarter = 2,
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to just initialize an empty string then you could:

```
public enum AgentLevel : int {

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute(Value = "")]
        Location = 1,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute(Value="Head Quarter")]
        HeadQuarter = 2,
    }
```